# Как залить свои изменения с bitbucket-репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket

Всем привет!

Получил от клиента доступ к php/laravel приложению на Digital Ocean и зайдя по ssd в корне проекта увидел:

```
root@Box-Site-Server:/var/www/html/sitebox# ls -l
total 868
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   3024 Feb  1 13:51 Vagrantfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     460284 Jun 29 09:01 _ide_helper.php
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data   4096 May 14 15:59 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   1686 Feb  1 13:51 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  1 13:51 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       1630 May 14 15:59 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     180623 Jun 29 09:01 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 14 15:59 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  1 13:51 database
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      91214 Jun 29 08:26 dump290518.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   1125 Feb  1 13:51 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   1040 Feb  1 13:51 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 May 14 15:59 public
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   3550 Feb  1 13:51 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  1 13:51 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 29 09:01 routes
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      67751 May 14 15:59 select2.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    563 Feb  1 13:51 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May 14 15:59 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  1 13:51 tests
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  1 13:51 the-box
drwxr-xr-x 44 www-data www-data   4096 May 14 16:03 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    549 Feb  1 13:51 webpack.mix.js
# ls -l 
total 16 
drwxr-xr-x 14 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 29 09:01 sitebox 
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     11321 Feb  1 13:39 index.html
```

1) Первое что меня удивило так это отсутствие каталога .git Это предыдущие разработчики проект загружали через ftp или каталог .git не отображается командой ls ?

2) Мне клиент дал проект в *.zip каталоге и внеся в него ряд изменений, я загрузил его в новый репозиторий на bitbucket, клиента так как клиент
хотел уйти с bitbucket-а бывших разработчиков

3) Теперь мне нужно залить свои изменения с другого(нового) bitbucket-репозитория...

Как это лучше сделать ?

MODIFIED :

Судя с команды

```
# git branch
* develop
```

там бранч только один.
Подмкажите, плиз как 
1) заменить remote/origin в git?
2) настроить доступ к новому репозиторию (ключ) ?

И можно ли ссылочку на описание как это сделать ?

MODIFIED 2:

выполнив

```
 git remote rm origin
 git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ>/<ИМЯ РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ>.git
```

и делая pull получаю ошибку:

## git pull origin develop

```
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

develop - единстивенный branch проекта

Открыв под рутом ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub - я вижу в нем емейл моего клиента(он же владелец репозитория добавляемый командой

```
git remote add origin
```

)

До того как я удалил старый origin я входил в систему без пароля по ssh-ключам. 
свой pub ssh файл я высылал предыдущим разработчикам.
У меня в Bitbucket->Settings->ssh keys загружен мой  pub ssh файл.
Мне (или моему клиенту) нужно где то прописать мой  pub ssh в новом репозитории ?

Или добавить доступ как-то иначе?

MODIFIED 3:

Опишу чуть подробнее:
1) На моем локальном компьютере файл /home/serge/.ssh/id_rsa.pub уже создан
Я этот файл высылал предыдущим разработчикам и и поэтому в вистему linux вхожу под рутом не вводя пароль

2) Этот же файл из 1) загружен у меня на bitbucket : https://imgur.com/a/UdXcKTm  У него видна дата обращение за сегодня
Это я еще раз пытался выполнить

```
git pull origin develop
```

3) Видимо где-то еще нужно настроить гит на себя/на свой ssk key.
Где и как это сделать ?

4) Открыв под рутом ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub - я вижу в нем емейл моего клиента(он же владелец репозитория )откуда я и пытался пулить данные в 2)
Я пытался заменить содержимое этого файла(сохранив бекапную копию) заменить СВОИМ ключом из 1)
И получил ошибку :

```
# git pull origin develop
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Видимо заменять своим ключем НЕ НУЖНО ?

5) Вернув первоначальный ключ получаю другую ошибку:

```
# git pull origin develop
Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                                                                                                               
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                                                                                                                

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                                                                                                                          
and the repository exists.
```

Похоже дело в пунке 3) ?

Спасибо!

Comment: показать все файлы `ls -la`

Comment: посмотреть: `git status` или `git remote -v`

Comment: Да про git status - я догадался сам. И подскажите плиз про пункты 2) и 3) как лучше сделать ?

Comment: тут сложный вопрос, советовать ничего не могу. **Нужно хорошо понимать экосистему проекта**. Может в readme разработчики оставили инструкцию. А так в принципе если изменения не значительные: определить основную ветку, заменить remote/origin в git, настроить доступ к новому репозиторию (ключ), сделать pull, это всё.  В любом случае сначала сделайте резервную копию текущей версии.  (Я не работаю с Laravel, мож там есть какие нюансы, сборка или кеш...)

Comment: Посмотрите, плиз, в блок MODIFIED

Comment: Я пыталсяч сделать но получил ошибку посмотрите, плиз, в блок MODIFIED 2

Comment: ничего нет в MODIFIED 2

Comment: Подправил блок MODIFIED 2 с описанием ошибки: посмотрите, плиз

Comment: Добавил блок MODIFIED 3 : чуть подробнее.  Посмотрите, плиз .

Comment: я рекомендую перенести диалог в какой-нибудь чат, мы слишком усложняем

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80426/bitbucket-repo-fail

Answer (score 2):

**Рекомендации**: прежде чем выполнять такие задачи, нужно всё-таки познакомиться с данными технологиями поближе и потренироваться локально на своей рабочей станции.

Я бы сделал пустой репозиторий на Bitbucket и записал бы туда всё с сервера, а уже затем вносил изменения, это исключит возможные конфликты сразу.

### ПРИМЕРНЫЙ СЦЕНАРИЙ ВОЗМОЖНЫХ ДЕЙСТВИЙ!

> в первую очередь создайте резервную копию текущего состояния проекта, можно просто копию директории. И резервную копию базы данных. 
>   Например для директории: `cp -R /var/www/html/sitebox /var/www/html/sitebox-backup`.

Для доступа обычно используют SSH-ключи

```
# Например:
# распечатать в консоли содержание публичного ключа 
# (если используются стандартные) 

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 

# скопировать вывод и добавить в свой профиль на Bitbucket
```

замена одного [удаленного репозитория](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) на другой

```
 git remote rm origin
 git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ>/<ИМЯ РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ>.git
```

Далее синхронизировать ваши изменения

```
# если вы уже создали ветку develop (инициализировали git flow),
# то сливаем изменения и на этом все (если нет конфликтов)
git pull origin develop


# если же ваша основная ветка сейчас, допустим master,
# то придется сделать что-то подобное:

# получить данные с origin
git fetch origin

# объединить изменения develop и master 
# (здесь мы считаем, что мы в develop) 
git merge master

# записать их обратно, синхронизировать изменения
git push origin --all
```

После всех манипуляций смотрим, что с проектом, проверяем работу, смотрим логи сервера. Если все совсем не так, то у нас резервная копия, можем вернуть рабочее состояние проекта.

**ветка develop** - это одна из практик [git flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html), обычно её используют как основную ветку в разработке. В вашем случае она является еще и основной при публикации.

При слиянии изменений могут возникнуть конфликты и их нужно будет разрешить вручную.

Особое внимание нужно обратить на файлы конфигурации проекта. Некоторые из них могут быть в репозитории, а некоторые создаваться вручную на сервере.

p.s. Проблема, описанная в вопросе, на самом деле очень простая и не должна вызывать никаких затруднений. Решить можно в один шаг просто клонировать файлы из нового репозитория и перекинуть файлы конфигурации. Но судя по вопросам в комментариях глубина не понимания... уж слишком. Поэтому в ответе указаны некоторые моменты, касающиеся любых проектов, может кому и пригодиться.